# Monaco Editor Never Trigger Auto Completion

Tags: monaco-editor

```
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';

const container = document.createElement('div');
container.style.width = '100vw';
container.style.height = '100vh';
document.body.appendChild(container);

monaco.languages.register({ id: 'typescript' });
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('typescript', {
  triggerCharacters: ['.'],
  provideCompletionItems() {
    // never do this
    return {
      suggestions: []
    }
  },
})
const editor = monaco.editor.create(container, {
  automaticLayout: true,
  quickSuggestions: true,
});
const model = monaco.editor.createModel('', 'typescript', monaco.Uri.parse('file///test/1.ts'));
editor.setModel(model);
```

I use monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api to import monaco,so I can handle all the features for typescript,but I find out that registerCompletionItemProvider api do not work.

Do not know why....

Comment: I just solve this problem, editor.api just add editor api without any widget controller. To solve this problem, just need to import editor.all entry.